# ReactJs / Native with Socket - Best Practices

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket

I'm facing some performance issues when using socket connections with react. Specially when I need to update some state inside a listener/subscription etc. So, in order to have a better understanding about "how to", I'd like to know the "best practices" to have a connection with socket, share it instance, abstract subscriptions/listeners in hooks, avoid re-renders etc.

I read a lot of "chat" tutorials which have same basics infos, I'm looking for "real life" code organisation etc.

If anyone have a time to show some links or docs or even a code example I'll appreciate a lot.

Thanks